# Using same transaction in workflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, transactions, workflow

Pardon me if my question looks stupid but I am totally new to Workflow. What I am trying to do is : I have some database hits inside the Workflow Foundation project and some in ASP.NET application. What I am trying to achieve is perform database operations inside Workflow foundation and ASP.NET in the same transaction. Tell me is it possible? I am using linq2sql.

Here is my code:

```
 using(var context = new MyDBContext())
 {
     context.Transaction = context.Connection.BeginTransaction();

     //Here I am calling my Workflow function

     using (WorkflowRuntime workflowRuntime = new WorkflowRuntime())
    {
        AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        workflowRuntime.WorkflowCompleted += delegate(object sender, WorkflowCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            waitHandle.Set();
            if ((string)e.OutputParameters["OutputMessage"] != "")
                msg = "Workflow error : " + (string)e.OutputParameters["OutputMessage"];
        };
        workflowRuntime.WorkflowTerminated += delegate(object sender, WorkflowTerminatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Exception.Message);
            waitHandle.Set();
        };

        WorkflowInstance instance = workflowRuntime.CreateWorkflow(typeof(MyWorkflow),           parameters);
        instance.Start();            
        waitHandle.WaitOne();
     }

     //DB Operation in ASP.NET 
     context.DbOperation();
     context.SubmitChanges();
     context.Transaction.Commit();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.  `instance.Start()` returns immediately. The actually workflow activities will run in a different thread (and potentially in different processes or different machines). You'll have to manage transactions within the workflow.

Comment: Even if I manage the transaction inside Workflow, how can I put the full db operation in one transaction? I mean 50% of my db operation is in Web Application and 50% in Workflow.

Comment: You can feed the workflow with data read from database, let the workflow process and only update the database when the workflow terminates.

Comment: you mean pass the whole data as parameter to Workflow and perform db operation?